# When looping through an object, how can i programmatically create variables of the same name?

Tags: javascript

I have some objects that look like this, but with several vehicles listed

```
let snapshot = [
    {
        "vehicle": "2015 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium",
        "link": "details9.html",
        "img": "css/images/vehicles/progressiveJPG/spotlight-mustang2.jpg",
        "trim": "GT Premium 2dr Coupe",
        "price": 16998,
        "priceSpecial": 19000,
        "priceAvg": 21470,
        "priceMonthly": 253,
        "miles": 37132,
        "milesAvg": 31029
    }
]
```

I would then like to loop through with something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.length; i++) {
    let vehicle = snapshot[i].vehicle;
    let link = snapshot[i].link;
    let img = snapshot[i].img;
    let trim = snapshot[i].trim;
    let price = snapshot[i].price;
    let priceSpecial = snapshot[i].priceSpecial;
    let priceAvg = snapshot[i].priceSpecial;
    let priceMonthly = snapshot[i].priceMonthly;
    let miles = snapshot[i].miles;
    let milesAvg = snapshot[i].milesAvg;
}
```

I would then configure my output using template strings and plugging in those variables where needed. My question is, can I dynamically create these variables that have the same name as the object key or is it even necessary. Should I just refer to each item as `snapshot[i].vehicle` for instance?

Comment: [That isn't JSON!](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: what do you do after getting single variables?

Comment: lol, snapshot[0].vehicle - u dont need any loop or what, u have it man:)

Comment: Please do not deconstruct every single property of an object into their own variables.

Comment: @NinaScholz i'll use them to make my output and then add it to the dom.

Comment: @Jacob `snapshot` here is an array, do you want to say you want to extract the properties of the first item of `snapshot` array ?

Comment: @JacobJ, please add that part as well.

Comment: @Quentin so my data file shouldn't be snapshot.json it should be snapshot.js? thanks for the link, i'll read through in more detail

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you can use a `with` block but this is *highly not recommended*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, can I dynamically create these variables that have the same name as the object key or is it even necessary. Should I just refer to each item as snapshot[i].vehicle for instance?

You are currently doing it just fine

```
for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.length; i++) {
    let vehicle = snapshot[i].vehicle;

    console.log(vehicle)
    console.log(snapshot[i].vehicle)
}
```

The above code prints out the same value twice, just through different handles

Weather you should put all the properties inside a corresponding variable, or if you should just directly refer to snapshot[i] is basically up to you. I usually opt for the variables solution when the code gets too messy to read with ease.

I suggest you code for readability rather than for some notion of efficiency that won't have your script run noticeably faster anyway

Answer (score 2):

```js
const snapshot = [{
        "vehicle": "2015 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium",
        "link": "details9.html",
        "img": "css/images/vehicles/progressiveJPG/spotlight-mustang2.jpg",
        "trim": "GT Premium 2dr Coupe",
        "price": 16998,
        "priceSpecial": 19000,
        "priceAvg": 21470,
        "priceMonthly": 253,
        "miles": 37132,
        "milesAvg": 31029
}];

    for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.length; i++) {
        const {
           vehicle,
           link, 
           img, 
           trim, 
           price, 
           priceSpecial, 
           priceMonthly, 
           miles, 
           milesAvg
        } = snapshot[i];
     
        console.log(vehicle,
           link, 
           img, 
           trim, 
           price, 
           priceSpecial, 
           priceMonthly, 
           miles, 
           milesAvg)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create array of object, then you can retrieve values as your give example. Create array of object like.

```
let snapshot = [ { "vehicle": "2015 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium", "link": "details9.html", "img": "css/images/vehicles/progressiveJPG/spotlight-mustang2.jpg", "trim": "GT Premium 2dr Coupe", "price": 16998, "priceSpecial": 19000, "priceAvg": 21470, "priceMonthly": 253, "miles": 37132, "milesAvg": 31029 },{ "vehicle": "2015 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium", "link": "details9.html", "img": "css/images/vehicles/progressiveJPG/spotlight-mustang2.jpg", "trim": "GT Premium 2dr Coupe", "price": 16998, "priceSpecial": 19000, "priceAvg": 21470, "priceMonthly": 253, "miles": 37132, "milesAvg": 31029 },{ "vehicle": "2015 Ford Mustang EcoBoost Premium", "link": "details9.html", "img": "css/images/vehicles/progressiveJPG/spotlight-mustang2.jpg", "trim": "GT Premium 2dr Coupe", "price": 16998, "priceSpecial": 19000, "priceAvg": 21470, "priceMonthly": 253, "miles": 37132, "milesAvg": 31029 }]
```